# NHibernate : InvalidCastException

Tags: nhibernate

I am getting an InvalidCastException when connecting to sybase db.

When i call BuildSessionFactory() i am gettign following error. Can somebody tell me what could be the reason...

"Unable to cast object of type 'Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection' to type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection'."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a newer version of the Sybase provider, that is built for .Net 2.0+.